# Number of positive solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the number of positive solutions to

$$ (x^{1000} + 1)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{998}) = 1000x^{999}? $$

I tried to solve it.
First I used by using sum of Geometric Progression.
Then the equation becomes too complicated and is in the power of 1998.
How can I get the number of positive solutions with that equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its x to the power 1000 , and x to the power 998 , and x to the power 999. i am sorry i tried but it was not coming in proper format.

Comment: When exponents have multiple digits, you need to put curly braces (i.e., { } ) around them.

Comment: Since $(1-x^2)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + … + x^{998})= 1-x^{1000}$ we have $1 + x^2 + x^4 + … + x^{998} = \frac{1-x^{1000}}{1-x^2}$ so $$(x^{1000}+1)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + … + x^{998})=\frac{(1+x^{1000})(1-x^{1000})}{1-x^2}=\frac{1-x^{2000}}{1-x^2}$$ hence we are looking for solutions to $\frac{1-x^{2000}}{1-x^2}=1000x^{999}$. Equivalently, we want $$0=(1-x^{2000})-(1000x^{999})(1-x^{2000})=1000x^{2999}-x^{2000}-1000x^{999}+1.$$

Comment: It should rather be $(1 - x^{2000} - 1000x^{999} + 1000x^{1001}) = 0.$

Answer (score 5):

For a cleverness free solution:

The number of positive roots counting multiplicity is $2$: the root $1$ is repeated twice.

You can use [Descartes' rule of signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), which is a general method which can be useful sometimes.

Your equation (after multiplying by $x^2-1$) is

$$ P(x) = x^{2000} - 1000x^{1001} + 1000x^{999} - 1 = 0$$

which has $3$ sign changes.

So the number of positive roots is either $1$ or $3$ (counting multiple roots multiple times).

The derivative is $$P'(x) = 2000 x^{1999} - 1000\times 1001 x^{1000} + 1000 \times 999 x^{998}$$

Notice that $P(1) = 0$, $P'(1) = 0$.

Since $1$ is a root, and also of the derivative, the number of positive roots is $3$, counting $1$ at least two times.

But since we introduced an extraneous positive root by multiplying by $x^2 -1$, the number of positive roots of your original equation, counting multiplicity is $2$.

The second derivative

$$P''(x) = 2000\times 1999 x^{1998} - 1000\times1000\times1000 x^{999} + 1000 \times 999 \times 999$$

and $P''(1) = 0$. Thus the root $1$ is of multiplicity $2$.

This also applies to the equation $x^{2n} - n(x^{n+1} - x^{n-1}) - 1 = 0$ for $n \gt 1$.

See Also: [Sturm's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

Comment: how it can be solved as A.M. >= G.M. as you wrote in the below comment?

Comment: @vikiiii: Tao's answer has it: "since $1 + x^2 + \dots + x^{2m-2} \ge m x^{m-1}$ (algeraic average is great than blah...)".

Answer (score 3):

Consider$$(x^{m} + 1)(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{m-2}) = mx^{m-1}?$$
by multiplying $x^2-1$ in tow sides of equation,we have
$$(x^{m} + 1)(x^m-1)=mx^{m-1}(x^2-1)$$,
Last we have
$$x^{2m} - m(x^{m + 1} - x^{m - 1}) - 1 = 0 \tag{#}$$
Factorization
$$\begin{align*}
&x^{2m} - m(x^{m + 1} - x^{m - 1}) - 1\\
&=(x^{2m}-1)-mx^{m-1}(x^2-1)\\
&=(x^2-1)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots x^{2m-2})-mx^{m-1}(x^2-1)\\
&=(x^2-1)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots x^{2m-2}-mx^{m-1})\\
\end{align*}$$
since $1+x^2+x^4+\cdots x^{2m-2}\geq mx^{m-1}$(algebraic average is great than geometry average $\forall x>0$)if and only if $1=x^2= \cdots$ ,then$$1+x^2+x^4+\cdots x^{2m-2}= mx^{m-1}$$
so the root of equation(#)is $1$ and -$1$,but sine we first multiply with$(x^2-1)$,
so maybe there are some  extraneous roots in it,substitute $1$ and$-1$ for original equation,we conclude that the root of original equation is $1$.

Comment: Just simply multiplying out $(1+x^{1000})(1 + x^2 + \dots + x^{998})$ gives us $1 + x^2 + x^4 + \dots + x^{998} + x^{1000} + \dots + x^{1998}$. Now we can apply AM $\ge$ GM. There is no need to bring $x^2 -1$ in.

Comment: @Aryabhata you are right.

Comment: There is no need to even multiply...You can apply the AM-GM inequality directly to $1+x^{1000}$ and $1 + x^2 + \dots + x^{998}$...

Answer (score 0):

I think a family of problems to consider would be $x^{2n} - n(x^{n + 1} - x^{n - 1}) - 1 = 0.$ Substituting $ n = 1000$ we get your case.

Comment: This is more suited to be a comment.